# Factory of plain classes derived from generic specializations

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, refactoring, factory

I have a C# generic class `B<T>`. Also I have a set of derived classes `Di : B<Ti>`. All that classes are always created with the same set of parameters.
So it leads to spagetti code:

```
if (typeof(T) == typeof(A1)) {work with D1}
else if (typeof(T) == typeof(A2)) {work with D2}
...
```

Obviously I want to refactor the code in way it'll look like:

```
var dInst = GiveMeD<T>();
work with Di
```

How can I implement function `GiveMeD<T>()`?

**UPDATE:**

`work with Di` -> casting to base class `B<T>` and work with its interface.
The main problem here - each block of code differs in derived class constructor invocation.

Comment: Does "work with D1" differ from "work with D2" and so on?

Comment: public static T GiveMeD<T>(){ //code here }   The code here code will have a list of objects, you can write a LINQ query similar to this:  var objs=List.Where(p=>p.GetType()== T).

Comment: I'd say not Where(), but FirstOrDefault()...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refactor effectively the code this way then you must take into account that "working with `D1`" and "working with `D2`" must be the same and only the behavior must differ; that is, D1 and D2 must have a common "interface" (`B<T>`) and you should only leverage said "interface", otherwise you will start having spaghetti code all over the place again and ugly casts.

If this fits your needs (if it doesn't then you should reconsider your whole approach to the problem), the common pattern is to simply create a factory method where your spaghetti code will only be written once:

```
public static B<T> CreateD<T>()
{
    if (T is A1) return ... //here you can create a new instance of D1 or return a cached one, etc.
    else if (T is A2) return ...
}
```

A beautiful pattern I like to use when the consumer does not need know anything about `D1`, `D2`, etc. and only needs to know about `B<T>` is the following:

```
public class B<T>
{
    public B<T> CreateD<T>()
    {
        if (T is A1) return ... //here you can create a new instance of D1 or return a cached one, etc.
        else if (T is A2) return ...
        ...
    }

    private B() { } //note constructor is private, consumer can't create a B<T>

    private class D1: B<A1> { ... } //private nested types, not visible outside B<T>.
    private class D2: B<A2> { ... }
}
```

Now you have absolute control on how many `Di`s can be implemented, you expose one single general purpose `B<T>` and you guarantee to give back always the correctly specialized type without actually making the consumer have to know anything about it.

Comment: I have one doubt about such approach: should base class know about classes derived from it? I believe not.

Comment: @user2123007 And it doesn't. The fact that the derived classes are private nested classes in the base class is just a convenient pattern to hide implementation details from the consumer but thats it. Try to find one single piece of information `B<T>` has about `D1` or `D2` that it wouldn't have if the derived classes were not nested.

Comment: @user2123007 The private nested in base class pattern is a solution for very specific scenarios. Like I said, it covers special needs that are certainly not the general use case of inheritance. Its very likely that in your particular scenario this pattern is not the best approach and a regular factory method is more than enough.

Comment: @user2123007 A great example of how to use this pattern is this simple [immutable stack class](https://ericlippert.com/2014/10/16/producing-combinations-part-two/)